# Error in my own batch file

Tags: html, file, batch-file, cmd

Im making a log in batch file. that you can log into.
its part of my big batch file project...
but the problem is when i register and i log in it gives me the error i made in case someone logs in wrong but i know my username and password is right though?
can anyone edit my batch file so then it runs smoothly and also explain why you made the changes so i understand what went wrong?
heres the code.

```
@echo off
title LOG IN SCREEN v1.0
color 0a
if EXIST username.uf (
if EXIST password.uf (
goto Login
)) else (goto Reg)

:Reg
cls
echo Welcome to Register!
ping localhost 2 >nul
echo Register to continue
set /p U=Username:
set /p P=Password:
echo %U%>username.uf
echo %P%>password.uf
echo REGISTRATION COMPLETE!
pause
goto Login

:Login
cls
echo Welcome, Please Login to continue
set /p user=Username:
set /p pass=Password:
if %user%==username.uf (
if %pass%==username.uf (
goto welcome 
)) else (goto error)

:welcome
cls
echo Welcome to the Test Program!
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo Please Exit and come back when you think 
echo Program is up!
pause
exit

:error
cls
echo Error. Input Value = Incorrect
echo Error Code = .txt =/ u/p
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo Type goback to go back to previous screen
set /p er=
if %er%==goback goto Login 
if not %er%==goback goto error
```

Comment: Learn Powershell.  Or VBScript.  Or Perl or C# or VB.Net.  *ANYTHNG* but a .bat file for anything more complicated than two or three lines.  IMHO...

Comment: I agree with @paulsm4 that .bat aren't the most comfortable, but that doesn't invalidate the question.  To improve your question, try to make the goal of your code clearer. A good question contains a clear goal/outcome, some code and it's known problems. Make those elements as clear as you can; use headers, be concise. You'll attract more valuable attention that way.

Answer (score 1):

in your :login section you check if %user% is identical to "username.uf" Same with Password

```
if %user%==username.uf (
if %pass%==username.uf (
goto welcome 
)) else (goto error)
```

Replace this block with:

```
set /p us=<username.uf
set /p pa=<password.uf
if "%user%"=="%us%" (
if "%pass%"=="%pa%" (
goto welcome 
)) else (goto error)
```

`set /p` asks for input, `<file.tx`t takes this asked input from a file.
I used `"` within the if command, because it would give a syntax error, if one of the variables should be empty